# Type Constraints in Typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

For fun I'm building a parser library. In this library I have a `Parser` data type:

```
data Parser e a = Parser (String -> Either e (a, String))
```

I'm able to define `Functor` and `Applicative` instances of `Parser`, but I don't think I can make an `Alternative` instance without constraining the "error" type or the "value" type the parser could return. Originally, this made me create an `Applicative` instance for when the error types are `String` messages, but I realized that I should be able to release this constraint to any message data type that has an `Alternative` (or maybe `Monoid` instead?) instance as well. With that in mind I wrote this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
instance Alternative e => Alternative (Parser e)
  where
    empty = Parser $ \s -> Left empty
    (<|>) (Parser p1) (Parser p2) = Parser $ \s -> tryParser s p2 $ p1 s
      where
        tryParser s p2 (Left _ ) =  p2 s
        tryParser _ _ x          = x
```

Unfortunately, this fails to compile. When I load it into ghci I get this error message:

```
Parsertest.hs:31:47:
    Expecting one more argument to `e'
    In the instance declaration for `Alternative (Parser e)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

When I search online, this seems to be the solution, but it doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Alternative` is for type constructors of kind `* -> *`, so if you say

```
instance Alternative e => ....
```

then `e` has to be a type **constructor**, not a type. So `e` could be `[]` or `Maybe` or something, but not `Int`.

Alternative's operator is `<|>` which has type `Alternative e => e a -> e a -> e a`. This forces `e` to take an argument to make a type, like `Maybe` has to take an argument, eg `Maybe Int`.

Use `Monoid` instead of `Alternative`, because it's a type class instead of a constructor class. It's operator `mappend` has type `Monoid e => e -> e -> e` which is what you want for combining errors.

Comment: That makes things compile again. Do you know where I can read up on when Monoid, Alternative, MonadPlus make sense to be used?

Comment: Wellllll, I wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13115196/1598537) and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13174738/1598537) on a similar topic ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080606)) if you're happy with rather theoretical discussions there. If you want more practical advice after reading them, you could try asking that as a new question, but be careful to make it clear that you've read them and that you want guidance for when to choose them, or if it's a minor clarification of one of those answers, ask in a comment.

Comment: @chanko I should have said that Alternative _is_ right for the parser, whilst Monoid makes sense for the error type.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that if I'm keeping with the applicative parser that I should keep the Alternative instance. Reading those links is making me consider extending my parser type to have a null parser instead. This way the alternative instance structure doesn't have to rely on the internals of the parser itself. Thank you for helpful links!

Comment: @chanko08 I think `<|>` should backtrack and use the second parser if the first one fails. (This is what parsers I've used do, and it allows you to replace `|` in a grammar with `<|>` in code. Therefore it should be looking at the input - the internals of the parser are relevant I think. Making a Null parser is easier, but failure and backtracking are more useful. The problem is that backtracking is hard without the Wadler's "How to replace failure with a list-of-successes" approach.

Comment: Yeah that's what my implementation does for `<|>`, this to me is more of an issue of what makes sense for `empty` to be. As you say, if I go with a `NullParser` extension to my parser than I see issues with how errors will propogate. If I go with the current solution than I'm forcing structure on the error type where I'm not really seeing is necessary. In the end, the structure probably isn't a big deal really, I just have some design things to mull over. Thanks for the feedback!