# Reading lines in haskell until non-empty string

Tags: haskell, io, getline, string, monoids

I am trying to read lines from input in Haskell until I find a non-empty line.
Actually, I know how to do it simply using the following code:

```
notEmpty [] = return ""
notEmpty (l:xs) = do
  s <- l
  if s /= "" then return s
             else notEmpty xs

getLine' = notEmpty $ repeat getLine
```

Test (I typed two empty lines then 'foo'):

```
*> getLine'


foo
"foo"
```

However, for the sake of exercise, I am trying to achieve this using Monoids (http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids), trying to mimick the First/getFirst Monoid (see link).

I first created a Monoid on lists that fits my needs (concatenation only keeps the first argument):

```
newtype FirstSt a = FirstSt { getFirstSt :: [a] }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

instance Monoid (FirstSt a) where
    mempty = FirstSt []
    FirstSt [] `mappend` x = x
    FirstSt s  `mappend` _ = FirstSt s
```

Which works well on a infinite list of strings (thanks to laziness):

```
> getFirstSt . mconcat . map FirstSt $ ["", "", "foo", "", "bar"] ++ repeat ""
"foo"
```

However, I can't get it to work in the IO Monad. I tried the following:

```
ioFirstSt = (=<<) (return . FirstSt)
getLine'' = getFirstSt <$> mconcat <$> (sequence . map ioFirstSt $ repeat getLine)
```

Which has the correct type:

```
*> :t getLine''
getLine'' :: IO [Char]
```

However, Haskell keeps wanting to evaluate the whole list before giving it to `mconcat`...
In there a way to keep laziness while navigating in the Monoid/Monad scope?

Comment: I believe that `sequence` for the `IO` monad is not lazy enough for this to work, it will try to evaluate the entire list of `IO` actions before returning the result.

Comment: BTW, you can avoid the intermediate infinite list if you simply use `getLine' = getLine >>= \s -> if s/="" then return s else getLine'`. Still, the monoid approach is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is excellent. Monoid is a great structure for this, but sadly as bheklilr points out, `sequence` is going to perform all the IO regardless.

### Theory vs practicality with a nod to Alternative

It would be nice to make `instance Monoid (IO String)` but we'd have to wrap it in a `newtype` to get it to compile, but then we'd lose some interoperability with other IO, so let's just write the functions without the instance.

I like to use `<>` instead of `mappend`, but it's taken, and `<|>` is also taken for `Alternative`, which is like a Monoid structure for Applicative functors, and you should certainly look into it. I wrote a bit about Alternative in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174738/1598537).

Anyway, let's use `<||>` and copy the fixity of `<>`:

```
infixr 6 <||>
```

### Making a Monoid of a Monad of Eq Monoids

We can make a monoid out of `IO String` because we can check the value returned to see if it's `""` and then do the next action if not. That's equivalent to using `==` to check whether we have `mempty`, so we can generalise to `IO s` as long as `s` is a Monoid with an Eq instance. Secondly, we don't need it to be `IO`, we could use any Monad:

```
(<||>) :: (Monoid s, Eq s, Monad m) => m s -> m s -> m s
m <||> n = do
    x <- m
    if x == mempty then n else return x
```

Notice that that's lazy about computing `n` - it doesn't bother if we're happy with the output of `m`. We could then define `main = getLine <||> getLine <||> getLine >>= print` to give the user up to 3 chances of entering something non-blank for us to print.

### Identity and list concatenation

Mathematically that's a monoid with identity

```
msempty :: (Monoid s, Monad m) => m s
msempty = return mempty
```

Let's also define the equivalent of `mconcat :: Monoid s => [s] -> s`:

```
msconcat :: (Monoid s, Eq s, Monad m) => [m s] -> m s
msconcat = foldr (<||>) (return mempty)
```

Which lets us rewrite as `main = msconcat [getLine,getLine,getLine] >>= print`

### Lazily combining infinitely many monadic monoids

The real test of laziness here is infinite lists of actions:

```
main = msconcat (repeat getLine) >>= print
```

That works fine, and terminates within a finite time if the user ever does something other than enter nothing. Hooray!

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. It seems sequence is not lazy for the IO Monad, which makes sense as it is important to guarantee ordering of IO. I still have much to learn in Monads/Monoid!