# Why is guard based on Alternative?

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor

Why is `guard` based on `Alternative`?

```
guard :: Alternative f => Bool -> f ()
-- guard b is pure () if b is True,
-- and empty if b is False.
```

I ask because `guard` only uses the `empty` from `Alternative`. It doesn't use `<|>` from `Alternative` at all. So why bother using `Alternative` in the first place?

I guess this is because there is some unstated idea behind `Alternative`'s `empty` that matches perfectly with what we're trying to accomplish with `guard` (stop on `False`, continue on `True`). If this is the case, please enlighten me about this unstated idea.

Yet at the same time, if feels that we're just ignoring `<|>`. It feels almost as if `guard` is not "fully capturing" what `Alternative` is all about. I hope that makes sense. To make it more concrete: Why didn't they invent another type class called something like `Stoppable` (or `Abortable`) and used that instead of `Alternative`?

Comment: You also need `pure`. Sure, you could have a `Pure` class providing `pure`, and a `Empty` class providing `empty`, and have `Alternative` require both. For pragmatic reasons, though, one does not always split a class into single-method classes.

Comment: Pragmatic or historic reasons in this case?

Comment: I think it's because there aren't types, which can implement `empty` and can't implement `(<|>)`. So, theoretical a type class `Stoppable` will be equal to `Alternative` (set of types will be equal).

Comment: @freestyle: funny enough, PureScript defines `Alternative` via `Plus` (provides `empty`), which is based on `Alt` (provides `(<|>)`). So they follow the Semigroup/Monoid approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Historical reasons. It was envisioned like this in `MonadPlus`, which got its `Applicative` variant `Alternative` later, and no one has proposed to split `Alternative` into `AZero` and `AChoice` or similar.

---

`Alternative` is a *relatively* new idea, just like `Applicative`. Back when `guard` was first envisioned, it was based on [`MonadPlus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus), a `Monad` that should support choice and failure, just like `Alternative`. Its original type was thus

```
guard :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()
```

That was specified in the Haskell 98 report, where [`MonadPlus`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/monad.html) was already noted. Haskell 1.0 didn't use monads at all, by the way. When `Applicative` finally got a superclass of `Monad`, `Alternative` got a superclass of `MonadPlus`, and `mzero = empty` and `mplus = (<|>)`.

Well, now we know why `guard` uses `Alternative`. Because it was based on `MonadPlus` beforehand. So why is `MonadPlus` defined like this?

One would have to write a mail to SPJ or someone else from the committee to get their rationale from 1998, because just one year later, [Erik Meijer and Graham Hutton wrote their "Monadic Parsing in Haskell"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf) paper. If you have a look at the paper, you'll notice that *their* `MonadPlus` just works like you intend:

> ```
> class Monad m => MonadZero m where
>   zero :: m a
>
> class MonadZero m => MonadPlus m where
>   (++) :: m a -> m a -> m a
> ```

So it's certainly possible to handle this "stoppable" the way you've described it. However, there is simply no `base` class that currently defines `empty` without `Alternative`. There could be one, but it wasn't proposed yet.

Note that this is a recurring theme with Haskell classes. `Monoid` contains `mappend` and `mempty`. After its conception, someone noticed that there are certain types where `mappend` makes sense, but not `mempty`. For example

```
newtype Min a = Min a

combine :: Ord a => Min a -> Min a -> Min a
combine (Min x) (Min y) = Min (min x y)
```

Here, `mappend = combine` is clearly associative, whereas an empty `Min` isn't possible if we just use `Ord`, we would have to use `Bounded`. That's why there is now `Semigroup`, which isn't a base class of `Monoid` yet, but gives us that associative operation.

To come back to your original question: `guard` uses `Alternative`, because `Alternative` provides `empty`, and `empty` "stops" the evaluation in certain `Alternative`'s. There's no other class that contains that, ***yet***.

But with a proposal, there might be at some point, although I'm not sure what's the community's opinion on splitting `Alternative` is.

By the way, languages like PureScript split `Alternative`, although they split it the other way round…

For more information about `Alternative` and why I used `Monoid` as another example, see [Confused by the meaning of the 'Alternative' type class and its relationship to other type classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13080606/1139697).

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an oversight, per se. There's a legit design tradeoff between granularity and cohesiveness. I personally somewhat prefer the Haskell class hierarchy to the PureScript one. `empty` and `<|>` "go together" in a natural way.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I removed the judgement, it wasn't really appropriate.

Comment: It's also worth thinking about `MonadFail`, whose `fail` is kind of like `empty`, but which extends emptiness with `>>=` rather than recovery.