# Applicative Parser deriving Alternative without empty

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative, alternative-functor

From reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081604/568785), I understand that the inclusion of `empty` in `Alternative` was largely a design decision to make `Alternative` a monoid (and thus more powerful). It seems to me this was also because otherwise you couldn't express any laws for `Alternative`.

But this is a pain if I have a generic applicative parser like so:

```
newtype Parser err src target = Parser (ExceptT err (State [src]) target)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadState [src], MonadError err)
```

Clearly, we can get the same behavior as `<|>` and `many`/`some` from `Control.Applicative` with:

```
option :: Parser e s t -> Parser e s t -> Parser e s t
option parserA parserB = do
  state <- get
  parserA `catchError` \_ -> put state >> parserB

many :: Parser e s t -> Parser e s [t]
many parser = some parser `option` return []

some :: Parser e s t -> Parser e s [t]
some parser = (:) <$> parser <*> many parser
```

Even though none of these use `empty`, it seems like I am forced to re-implement them instead of deriving `Alternative`, because I can't conceive a generic way to instance `empty` for it (of course, I'd still need to instance `<|>` to get the preservation of `state` on `parserA` error, but then I could get `some`, `many`, `optional` and friends for free).

Digging into Parsec's source, it seems that it subverts this because it doesn't allow for custom error types (or at least, `Parsec` isn't parameterized by a custom error type):

```
instance Applicative.Alternative (ParsecT s u m) where
    empty = mzero
    (<|>) = mplus

instance MonadPlus (ParsecT s u m) where
    mzero = parserZero
    mplus p1 p2 = parserPlus p1 p2

-- | @parserZero@ always fails without consuming any input. @parserZero@ is defined
-- equal to the 'mzero' member of the 'MonadPlus' class and to the 'Control.Applicative.empty' member
-- of the 'Control.Applicative.Alternative' class.

parserZero :: ParsecT s u m a
parserZero
    = ParsecT $ \s _ _ _ eerr ->
      eerr $ unknownError s

unknownError :: State s u -> ParseError
unknownError state        = newErrorUnknown (statePos state)

newErrorUnknown :: SourcePos -> ParseError
newErrorUnknown pos
    = ParseError pos []
```

Taking inspiration from this, it seems like the only reasonable way around this is to have my generic parser wrap the user error type with something like:

```
 data ParserError err = UserError err | UnknownError

 newtype Parser err src target = Parser (ExceptT (ParserError err) (State [src]) target)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadState [src], MonadError err)
```

And then `empty` can be:

```
empty = throwError UnknownError
```

This just *feels* wrong, though. This wrapping only exists to appease the requirement for an `empty` and it makes consumers of this generic parser do more work to handle errors (they also must handle `UnknownError` now and unwrap their custom errors). Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the problem correctly; Why not simply require there to be a `Default` instance for the error or something along those lines? No need add wrapping/unwrapping (unless you want to use it with an error type that doesn't have a default, in which case you'd just do *both* the wrapping and the unwrapping on the use end)

Comment: I considered requiring a default. Decided against it because I wasn't sure I had the chops to make such a monad (I think I know how to though). Short of that, the entire thing I was trying to avoid was the unwrapping on the user end (presumably my library would need to wrap in its own error type). Although given that Megaparsec and Parsec just define their own, so it seems like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem of standard `base` hierarchy. It's not extremely modular. In some perfect world `Alternative` would be splitted into three type classes if we want to achieve maximum modularity.

See `Alternative` definition in PureScript world:

- https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-control/3.3.0/docs/Control.Alternative#t:Alternative

Like this:

```
class Functor f <= Alt f where
  alt :: forall a. f a -> f a -> f a  -- alt is (<|>)

class Alt f <= Plus f where
  empty :: forall a. f a

class (Applicative f, Plus f) <= Alternative f
```

So, if type hierarchy is modular enough you could implement `Alt` for your `Parser` type (and have all `<|>`-only-related functions) but not `Alternative`. If `Alternative` is `Monoid` then `Alt` is `Semigroup`: you can *append* elements but you don't have *empty* element.

Note, that previously in GHC `base` package `Applicative` wasn't a superclass of `Monad`, `Semigroup` wasn't in `base` and only in GHC-8.4.1 `Semigroup` will be superclass of `Monoid`. So you can expect that in some future similar thing (modularization) can happen with `Alternative`.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.2.2/docs/Data-Functor-Alt.html

Comment: Very interesting to see that in other worlds the more modular choice was made! Thanks for the detail! Also interesting that in lieu of an `empty` the laws are just for associativity and distributivity. I guess we can only wait for this modularization to mature over time. As a tangent, I'm curious what you think about the design choice of having a wrapper error type to `instance Alternative`. Parsec as reference art didn't suggest to me whether this was a good or bad approach. Perhaps you have more experience?

Comment: @BaileyParker Well, `parsec` is very old and you should use `megaparsec` (at least for reference): https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec#megaparsec-vs-parsec As I can see from `megaparsec` sources, it also defines `empty` using special error type: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-6.4.0/docs/src/Text-Megaparsec.html#line-441 I think this is a necessary workaround for current type class hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to megaparsec! It looks like fantastic reference art. And thanks for your answer :)