# How do I call a monoid that also supports lifting?

Tags: list, haskell, monoids

What I mean is a device like a list:

```
mempty = [ ]
lift x = [x]
mappend = (++)
```

Is it merely `IsList`?

Answer (score 6):

Given the framing of your question, I would be inclined to characterise your lift...

```
(:[]) :: a -> [a]
```

... as reflecting how lists are an encoding of [the free monoid for Haskell types](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/07/21/free-monoids/). In particular, the universal property (illustrated by the diagram at the end of the *Category Theory for Programmers* chapter linked to above) implies that:

```
-- q is an arbitrary a -> m function, with m being an arbitrary monoid.
foldMap q . (:[]) = q
```

---

As far as the types go, `Alternative` might seem to also express what you are looking for: `empty` and `(<|>)` are generally expected to be monoidal operations, and `pure` from `Applicative` could be taken as your lift. However, I'm not sure if there is any connection that might be drawn between `pure` and the `Alternative` methods that would clarify the role of `pure` in such a construction. (On this latter point, you might find [this tangentially related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080606/confused-by-the-meaning-of-the-alternative-type-class-and-its-relationship-to) which discusses the relationship between `Alternative` and `Applicative` interesting.)

Comment: Isn't there a little more to the universal property? For one thing, `foldMap f x <> foldMap f y = foldMap f (x <> y)` and `foldMap f mempty = mempty` (`foldMap` is a monoid morphism). But there's one more piece: uniqueness of `foldMap`. That basically says that *every* `f a` can be formed using `pure` and `Monoid` operations.

Comment: @dfeuer Yup, there is more to it. I wasn't, and I still am not, entirely sure about how to wire that to the context of this question; in the meantime, I have changed "means that" to "implies that" to better suggest it doesn't end there.

Comment: I do not actually think it necessarily has to be a free monoid. Since I am not requiring a projection to any other monoid, it may conflate elements as it wills.

Comment: Also, actually I would like to have a class for free monoids indeed, but Alternative is usually lossy: it acts like `const`: `x <|> y = x` — in most all instances I have been dealing with so far, be it applicative parsers _(where this operator makes asymmetric choice)_ or monads _(where it is used when trying actions until the first successful)_. I propose instead that `IsList` is what we should consider the free monoid class, as it witnesses the isomorphism inbetween all the instances _(through List)_.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov (1) If your lift is fully polymorphic on the element type (`a -> M a`), I don't think you can do any collapsing with it, except for sending everything to some `empty`. (2a) I don't feel there are enough noteworthy encodings of the free monoid to justify a separate type class. What we do have is `Foldable`, which says something broader: "this can be converted to the free monoid" (through either `toList` or `flip foldMap`). (2b) `Alternative` is indeed something quite different from the other possibilities we are considering.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about `Alternative` as @Robin Zigmond said:

```
instance Alternative [] where
    empty = []
    (<|>) = (++)
```

And if you want to know, it is also a `MonadPlus`:

```
instance MonadPlus []
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I should mention that I *think* there is something of an analogy between `lift` from `MonadTrans` and the free monoid I mention in my answer, in that transformers often are free constructions of some sort. I didn't mention it in my answer because that is a remote connection, and I haven't made it sufficiently clear to myself yet in order to be able to explain it well.